# Notice: Undefined variable: successMessage in

Tags: undefined, divide

I am getting the following error message on my site.

"Notice: Undefined variable: successMessage in /home/sites/synapsetechnologies.com/public_html/Login.php on line 107 Notice: Undefined variable: error in /home/sites/synapsetechnologies.com/public_html/Login.php on line 107"

Code: https://jsbin.com/biwutacufe/edit?html,output

I took a look at my codes but cannot figure out what is wrong. I have tried the console in Chrome but it doesn't give me a lot of info.

Thanks

Comment: initialize  $error & $successMessage if you are not setting a value for it in Login.php. or if you do not require $error & $successMessage; please remove echo $error.$successMessage; from your form

Comment: Yep, it works. Thank you so much!